# How to initialize a Generics?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a `ListView` with generics item, here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test5Pape extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test5Pape({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test5')),
      body: GenericsListView<RedItem>().create(),
    );
  }
}

class GenericsListView<T extends BaseItem> {
  ListView create() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        // How to initialize a generic?
        return T();
      },
    );
  }
}

class BaseItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseItem({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // override in subclass
  Widget config() {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return config();
  }
}

class RedItem extends BaseItem {
  @override
  Widget config() {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 40,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text('red'),
    );
  }
}
```

And showed an error:

[image]

The error is:

[image]

You can copy my code and test.

**What I wonder is how to initialize the generics.**

Comment: As for the "how to initialize the generics", the simple and short answer is - you can't. Dart is a strongly typed language and doesn't have any runtime capabilities like reflection or introspection. So, all types must be resolved in compile time. As such, `T()` isn't specific enough for the compiler to know which class it needs to instantiate as more than one satisfies the `extends BaseItem` condition.

Comment: @nstosic Dart *does* have reflection capabilities, just not when used in Flutter.

Comment: That's true. I didn't phrase it correctly.

Comment: @nstosic  `BaseItem` can call init, but the `T` which extends `BaseItem` can not, this is really ridiculous. I have to say Dart is really hard to use compared with Swift.